# GooglePlayServicesLib.dll.so' not found and android google map doesn't show

Tags: android, xamarin, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I integrate android google maps v2 in my application using xamarin.android and visual studio 2012 and I'am using google play services 13.0. It works perfectly well. But now, the map doesn't loads anymore and when I debugged it, I have seen this on output window **GooglePlayServicesLib.dll.so' not found**. I don't know how to fix it anymore, please help me.

Comment: So it's only when debugging that you get the problem?

Comment: No, the release version(apk) is not also working. Then I tried to debugged it so than I can Identify whats the problem that's the time I saw this error **GooglePlayServicesLib.dll.so' not found**

Comment: I am using Google Play Services 13.0

Comment: Whether your map view shows any information like download playserverice like that

Comment: Make sure you have update your sdk and installed the latest google play services.

Comment: nothing because I have both google play services and play store installed on my device. Now it only shows white screen with google logo and zoom in and out button. I thought it was just loading I waited more than 10 minutes nothing happens the map doesn't shows

Comment: What API level is your application targeting?

Also, examine the logcat output. Google Play services will dump some messages there that contain some clues as to why the maps aren't showing.

Answer (score 0):

Google made new Maps V2 API as a part of Google Play Services SDK. So before we start developing maps we need to download google play services from SDK manger. You can open SDK manager either from Eclipse or from android sdk folder.

`Open Eclipse ⇒ Windows ⇒ Android SDK Manager and check whether you have already downloaded Google Play Services or not under Extras section`. If not select play services and install the package.

[image]